# How to get to Catalan numbers recurrence relation from couting lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

I'm currently taking a probability theory class and I've been stuck on a problem where I can find the solution using one method but I dont get how my TA got to the catalan numbers from counting, so heres how it goes *(I didn't find any awnsers on HOW you get the recurrence relation i.e the reasonning that gets to it)*:

**Suppose we place someone on a lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2_{\geq0}$ and we want to count how many ways he can get to$ (n,n)$,  such that $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and the the person cant pass trough the diagonal $y=x$ and he can only walk northward or westward on that lattice.**

And here's my thoughts so far:

**Attempt on a solution using recurrence relation**

Let $C_k$ be the numbers of valid path from $(0,0)$ to $(k,k)| k\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$

Then $C_0 = 1$ *(because there's only one way to stay where you are... you stay)*

Moreover, if the person touch the diagonal at $(k,k)$, then he has $C_{n-k}$ ways to get to $(n,n)$ if he doesn't touch the diagonal again *(because its as if (k,k) was the new origin... I'm not sure from here).*

So by the product principle of counting, for every $C_k$ ways he can get to $(k,k)$ he has $C_{n-k}$ implies that he has $(C_{n-k})( C_k)$ ways to get to $(n,n)$.

However, my TA only wrote,

"let's consider the first time he touches the diagonal, then he has

$(C_0)(C_n) + (C_1)(C_{n-1}) + ... + (C_n)(C_0) = C_{n+1}$

So is my way of reasonning a good beginning and how do we get from his first sentence to that relation with a sum and $C_{n+1}$

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Take any valid catalan path $P$ from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$. Any such path has exactly $2(n+1)$ steps. This path ultimately must hit the diagonal at time $2(n+1)$. We're going to split these paths based on the times at which they touch the diagonal, prior to $2(n+1)$.

Let $t=t(P)$ denote the index of the *last-time prior to* $2n+1$ that $P$ touches the diagonal, with the convention that $t=0$ if the path never touched the diagonal. It's easy to see that $t$ must be even, i.e. $t=2k$. This partitions all possible paths $P$ into $n$ classes: $k=0,2,4,\cdots 2n$

Then any path can be mapped to such a $t$, hence it suffices to count the number of paths by figuring out how many paths belong to each class $t$. You found that for $t=2k$, it's $C_kC_{n-k}$, hence:

$$C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} C_kC_{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Total Catalan paths from $(0,0)$  to  $(n+1,n+1)$ is equal to $C_{n+1}$

Let us split all Catalan paths in some mutually exclusive paths based on the first time, they meet diagonal $y=x$ after $(0,0).$

Let use take a Catalan path meeting $y=x$ after $(0,0)$ first time at $(r,r),\,r$ can be $1,2,,3\cdots,n+1.$ This path can be thought as starting from $(1,0)$ going to $(r,r-1)$ and never crossing $y=x-1$ then from $(r,r-1)$ to $(r,r)$ and finally from $(r,r)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$

Number of paths from $(1,0)$ to $(r,r-1)$ and not crossing $y=x-1$ is equal to $ C_{r-1}$

Number of paths from $(r,r-1)$ to $(r,r)$ is $1$

Number of paths from $(r,r)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$ is $C_{n+1-r}$

$\implies$ Number of paths meeting y=x after $(0,0)$ first time at $(r,r)$ is $C_{r-1}\times 1\times C_{n+1-r}$

$\implies C_{n+1}=\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} C_{r-1}C_{n+1-r}$